# Git refs - why is it called heads instead of branches?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-refspec

Just curious when you look in the git/refs directory:

```
.git/refs/heads
.git/refs/tags
```

why is it called refs/heads instead of refs/branches?

Comment: All branches are heads, not all heads are branches.

Comment: can you give example of heads that are not branches? thx

Comment: I guess you already read it, but just in case, there's an entry (albeit very concise) in the glossary ([here](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefheadahead)).

Comment: From what I've read, it looks like `refs/heads` only contains branch heads. So you're right that it could be `refs/branches`. I could guess the reason, but I wouldn't be able to say for sure.

[This link](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-References) basically outright says that `refs/heads` are branches at the end.

Comment: http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/H/hysterical-reasons.html

Comment: Detached heads for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> can you give example of heads that are not branches?

A [detached head](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309) is not a branch.
But all branches are referenced by a HEAD, as direct reference to the last commit of their branch.